# Excel Concatenate multiple cell, one is the same the other change

Tags: excel, variables, concatenation, cell, fixed

I have an excel file. `B1` has the text value `ME`. `B2` has a number value `01`.
From `C1` to `C100` the values are `shot001` to `shot100`.

I would like to do a formula in `G1` that concatenates: `B1+B2+C1` then in `G2` I need`B1+B2+C2` then in `G3` I need `B1+B2+C3`.

I've done a formula in `G1 = CONCATENATE(B1,B2,"_",C1)`. If I drag the formula along the `G` column the value `B1` and `B2` change in `B3` and `B4`, then in `B5` and  `B6`.

My problem is that I don't know how to force the formula to use ALWAYS in each formula `B1` and `B2`.

Comment: Thank BRANDEN , you answer is very usefull. Ans also thanks to Taosique for your code.

Answer (score 3):

Use dollar `$` sign to fix cell coordinates. `$B1` will fix column `B` if you drag horizontally. `B$1` will fix row `1` if you drag vertically. `$B$1` will fix both row and column wherever you drag:

```
=CONCATENATE($B$1,$B$2,"_",C1)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the formula in G1 of:

```
=CONCATENATE(B1,B2,"_",C1) -> [B1][B2]_[C1]-> -> ME01_Shot001
```

then if you fill down each row will update the respective cell reference, so for example G2 will fill to:

```
=CONCATENATE(B2,B3,"_",C2)  -> [B2][B3]_[C2]-> 01_Shot002
```

To keep the formula always referring to cells B1 and B2, you need to lock them down using a $ in the code. This will keep the absolute value of the cell rather than the relative value. So, the formula for G1 should instead be:

```
=CONCATENATE(B$1,B$2,"_",C1)  -> [B1][B2]_[C1]-> ME01_Shot001
```

Then when you drag down, the formula in G2 will become:

```
=CONCATENATE(B$1,B$2,"_",C2) -> [B1][B2]_[C2]-> -> ME01_Shot002
```

You can read more about the use of $ and absolute vs. relative [HERE](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21)

Also, for future reference the below code would also work:

```
=B$1&B$2&"_"&C1 -> [B1][B2]_[C1]-> ME01_Shot001
```